# Why can't I join these two files on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, file

These are the two files that I would like to join these two files (One of them is .txt and another .tsv)

File 1 (.txt file) : Has two columns

```
string_1  abc...
string_2  bcd...
string_3  cde...
```

File 2 (.tsv file) : Has two columns

```
string_1  X...
string_2  Y...
string_3  Z...
```

I used this linux statement to join the files from commandline:

```
join -j 2 -o 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 2.1 file.txt file.tsv
```

But I get this error message upon execution:

```
join: invalid file number in field spec: ‘’
```

Comment: Do not give a space between the -o options so try with  -o 1.1,1.2,1.3, 2.1 and also be explicit in specifying the separator in file so say -t ' '   (single space?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there are several problems here.

First, you are asking join to join files using field 2 (`-j 2`), but from your input data it looks as if you actually want to join on field 1.  If I take your sample input and run:

```
join -j 2 file1.txt file2.txt
```

I will get no output, because there are no joinable lines.  Compare that with the output of running:

```
join file1.txt file2.txt
```

Which results in:

```
string_1 abc... X...
string_2 bcd... Y...
string_3 cde... Z...
```

Next, your arguments to `-o` look wrong. The `-o` option expects a single argument with no whitespace, as in:

```
-o 1.1,1.2,1.3,2,1
```

And if we use that, we get:

```
$ join -o '1.1,1.2,1.3,2.1' file1.txt  file2.txt
string_1 abc...  string_1
string_2 bcd...  string_2
string_3 cde...  string_3
```

But that argument *still* looks wrong, because your input files only
have two columns and you're trying to refer to a third column in the
first file (`1.3`).  And since field 1 is the common field between the
two inputs, it doesn't really make sense to include column `2.1` in
the output (since it will be identical to `1.1`).  This gets us:

```
$ join -o '1.1,1.2,2.2' file1.txt  file2.txt
string_1 abc... X...
string_2 bcd... Y...
string_3 cde... Z...
```

Which is exactly what we get by simply running `join file1.txt
file2.txt` with no arguments.

Comment: I iterated through each issue you mentioned and now I can join these files perfectly.